# c++ compiler issues - MinGW and visual studio c

Tags: visual-c++, include, g++, mingw

several issues with both compilers.

Firstly, I've manually installed MinGW c++ compiler - the automated install was failing to download anything - exactly according to the instructions on the MinGW website, including adding C:\MinGW\bin to PATH system-wide, and restarted afterwars.  However, g++ only launches if I cd to C:\MinGW\bin first.  Secondly, when I do that, I get an error 'no include path in which to search for iostream', and when I look in c:\MinGW\bin\include (where all the header files seem to be', iostream.h is not there.

Finally, I tried downloading visual studio c++ from MS's website, which gives me the installer package vc_web.exe - but when I run this, it fails to download anything.  My internet connection is otherwise fine so I can't think of any reason for this.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks
-confused

Answer (score 0):

As for Visual C++ Express, you can try the offline installer (which doesn't need an internet connection) http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso

And regarding g++, it'll be easier for you to download an IDE that includes g++ and that sets everything up for you, I recommend [CodeLite](http://www.codelite.org) but there's also [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26/)